# How to query for the active database name in Cypher/Neo4J?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

We have a multi-db setup on a stand-alone server. We can change the db which we query by `:use ...` where ... is the database to which queries are directed.

I would like to know if there is a query we can run to check which database we are currently running queries to, something like
`SHOW ACTIVE DATABASE` or something like that.

Tried ACTIVE, CURRENT but neither seems to work. Tried checking for a field in `SHOW DATABASES` which may indicate the database I am currently querying towards. Nothing there either...

This should be possible but I couldn't find any documentation to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query :

```
CALL db.info()
YIELD name
```